# Iterate over a Map<String, Map<String,String>> with logic iterate in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, struts-1

I have a map with this structure:

**category product value**

#### food   cake    5

...

I want to display this in a table with 3 columns. How can I iterate over the structure in JSP in order to obtain my purpose? In other words this is a structure with one key and multiples values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add more details yo your question

Comment: is your multiple values are comma seperated?

Comment: I have no idea what structure a bunch of bold text is trying to mean.